# Include/get access to one more table in the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have tables in my database with Products, Stock and Storages
The Stock table contains foreign keys to Products (ProductId) and Storages (StorageID).
Right now I'm trying to display Product details in a modal.
The information i'm able to display in the modal now is ProductName, Price and StorageId. I'm not intrested to display StorageId, but i want to display where the product is available (StorageName). So i need to include the Storage table to my view...

The problem is that i cant Include the Storage table in my controller, only the Stock table. Is that any solution to this?
Here is my controller...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(long? id)
    {

        var products = await _context.Products.Include(s => s.Stock)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.ProductId == id);

        return View(products);
    }
```

And here is my ProductModel

```
public partial class Products
{
    public Products()
    {
        Stock = new HashSet<Stock>();
    }

    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Stock> Stock { get; set; }
}
}
```

And StockModel

```
public partial class Stock
  {
    public long StockId { get; set; }
    public long Quantity { get; set; }
    public long? ProductId { get; set; }
    public int? StorageId { get; set; }

    public Products Product { get; set; }
    public Storage Storage { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Okay, let's first check if I understood you well. U want to access Storage obj from Stock obj? By seeing your code, did u tried something like this: `s.Stock.Storage.StorageName` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ThenInclude()` extension method of EF Core like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(long? id)
{

    var products = await _context.Products
              .Include(p => p.Stock)
                  .ThenInclude(s => s.Storage)
              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ProductId == id);

    return View(products);
}
```